# No completions in swift when using objective c class imported in bridging header

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, swift

In my project I have got two projects - library which is build as framework, and is used by main project.
When i added swift class to main project and imported the library classes into bridging header I am able to use that classes. As it all compiles fine. But classes from the library framework have no suggestions.

Any idea how to get the suggestions to appear for the classes from the framework ?

Comment: Did you try removing your project from derived data folder and clean it ?

Comment: Yes i did try it, did not help. But found the cause.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else having same issue.

In my framework library i had few issues:

- I did not had 'Umbrella header' (Header which has same name as the
  framework) with the proper imports.
- I did not had the *Build
  Settings > Packaging > Define Module* set to True.
- I did not set the *Product Module Name*.

Found this helpful:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_88